# Showing file beneath other in Visual Studio with .NET Core project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj

In my ASP.NET Core project the `.json` settings files are group under the main one. But if I use `.yml` instead, it won't do that.
In the old csproj there was a lot of XML for these kinds of things. But can't find any references to the settings files in it now.

[image: VS]

What kind of magic does this to the `.json` files?

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846144/213550

Comment: It's related, but it doesn't answer my question which is "What kind of magic does this to the .json files?".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846144/213550) suggest, use XML similar to:

```
<None Update="appsettings.*.yml">
  <DependentUpon>appsettings.yml</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

[image]

Note that you need the `Update`, not `Include` attribute

Comment: I guess this works, but would be nice to not have to do this with yml when I don't have to do it with json...

Comment: Well, I guess, this is a pre-defined behavior for `appsettings.json`. I don't think that this will be the same for any other json (not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [File Nesting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting) extension provided by Mads Kristensen, if you haven't already. According to the description, this allows you to both manually nest files and set up your own rules for automatic nesting.

You can just search for this under the Visual Studio Extensions and Updates component.

EDIT: According to the known issues, this is not supported in all project types:

> Due to missing or limited support for file nesting in certain project types, this extension will have no effect or be disabled. The project types are:
>
> Node.js projects (NTVS)
> ASP.NET Core (has built in rules for nesting)
> Apache Cordova
> Shared projects

Comment: it does not work neither with ASP.Net Core nor with .Net Core projects