# App.config for different environments folder structure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, app-config

I have multiple config files for the different environments for my C# application. They appear as subitems under App.config. The problem is I want to add a new option, in this case JMTelcom, but it appears outside the folder structure. The file seems to be working fine at compile time, but how do I make it appear next to its siblings?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can files be nested in VS2017 Solution Explorer for .NET Core (non-ASP.NET Core) projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846079/can-files-be-nested-in-vs2017-solution-explorer-for-net-core-non-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="App.*.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Add/append above lines to your .csproj file should do the trick. (Assuming your project is using .net core)